# jQuery And Javascript Changing checkbox' checked attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I have a mobile client and have a simple problem.

Here is my html part:

```
<label id="112233" for="checkbox-detailed_limit">Take Profit</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-detailed_limit"
id="checkbox-detailed_limit" data-mini="true"/>
```

I want to change checkbox's checked status, when the container page is displayed.

I have used javascript and jquery for this action but all failed.

Here are some examples:

```
$("#checkbox-detailed_limit").attr("checked", false).change();
$("#checkbox-detailed_limit").attr("checked", false).trigger("change");
$("#checkbox-detailed_limit").prop("checked", false);
$("#checkbox-detailed_limit").removeAttr("checked");
$('input:checkbox', $("#112233")).prop("checked", false);
$("#112233").filter(':checkbox').prop("checked", false);
$('input').filter(':checkbox').prop('checked',false);
$("#112233").children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
$("#112233").find("checkbox").attr("checked", false);
document.getElementById("checkbox-detailed_limit").checked = false;
```

Is there any way to help me?

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fHr2N/1/) with a working example.

Comment: so many questions on this already, how could you not have found this on SO?

Comment: Additionally, most of your *examples* actually work. Did you try changing `false` to **`true`**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a jquery-mobile problem, since these checkboxes will get enhanced.

```js
$("#checkbox-detailed_limit").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/checkboxes/methods.html

Comment: Works fine. Thank you for quick and constructive answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you really want, but you want to set checked status to checkbox ? then this can be done like this.

```
$("#checkbox-detailed_limit").prop("checked", true); //for jquery 1.7+ 

$("#checkbox-detailed_limit").attr("checked", true); //for jquery < 1.7
```

Answer (score 0):

**To Check the Check box:**

```
$("#"+id).attr("checked", "checked");
```

**To Uncheck the checkbox:**

```
$("#"+id).removeAttr("checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   $("#checkbox-detailed_limit").prop("checked", true);
   $("#checkbox-detailed_limit").prop("checked", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=foo]').attr('checked', !$('input[name=foo]').is(':checked'));
```

This script will toggle the checkbox and should work absolutely fine. If this is not working you have an error in your javascript code somewhere else. Using a console will help you finding your problem.